# Is there a jquery or ajax solution/framework where you can slide/drag to see the next pages?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, load, slider

I'm trying to create something where there's a constant navigation bar fixed at the top of the screen, and below it loads new full html pages (with iframe or something else).

I have found [this](http://3.s3.envato.com/files/1526824/index.html#load=instructions.html) where you load new full pages into the content area below, while maintaining the navigation bar at the top (which is also dynamic, as per the image for the page changing).

But I want to know how I can make it so that when you click for a new page to be loaded, it 'slides' to the new page like [this](http://www.interactivegoods.com/fss/#/introduction), or is draggable with your mouse like how pages in an ipad are.

This is my first posting here so hopefully I'm explaining myself right. Thank you in advance for any help or guidance!

Answer (score 0):

you basically have to build all of your pages when the master page is loaded. All the pages, except the first are invisible to the user because they are out of screen. When you click a button you can use [this jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/slideto) to make your window slide to the selected page.

You can make some optimization like loading the page only when requeste using ajax and not on the first load but the concept is the same.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply wezzy. The slideto plugin is interesting, but does it seem able to load separate full html pages, each with their own head, body, different scripts, etc.?

Comment: Hi A.L. if you want to load full pages i suggest you to use many iframe (one for page) in the main page and then ask the jQuery plugin to slide to the selected iframe

Comment: Thanks again wezzy. Do you think the slideto plugin could incorporate a fixed navigation at the top that changes dynamically depending on which iframe is loaded, like this http://3.s3.envato.com/files/1526824/index.html#load=instructions.html

Comment: You have to put the fixed part in the main page and put all the iframe inside a <div>. Than you can make that div to slide instead of the full page. This makes your navigation fixed (maybe it works also to make position:fixed to you navigation). Keep in mind that the plugin make the slide effect but it doesn't display anything, you have to create a menu by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Something like [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) might work for you.

Here's an example:
http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html